# unable to insert new row Sqlite, Ionic2

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I am trying to insert some data in sqlite, Ionic2. My code so far is

```
    appendUserLoginData(userData:Object): void {
    //console.log(userData);
    this.db.openDatabase({
      name: 'cbsapp.db',
      location: 'default' // the location field is required
    }).then(() => {
      this.db.executeSql(`INSERT INTO user_master (id, name,user_email) VALUES ('cc', 'bb', 'dd')`, []).then((data:any) => {
            console.log("INSERTED: " + JSON.stringify(data.rows));
        }, (err:any) => {
            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }, (err: any) => {
      console.error('Unable to open database: ', err);
    });
  };//end appendUserLoginData
```

Insert query run success but console.log shows `INSERTED: {"length":0}`, that means data is not inserted.
What am I doing wrong, please help.
Table is already created in some other function and shows Table created successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rows` would contain the data that is returned by a query. But the INSERT statement is not a query and does not return data.

The `rowid` of the inserted row is available in `data.insertedId`, the number of inserted rows, in `data.rowsAffected`.

Comment: OK, I am using SELECT query to get the inserted rows, after Insert is successful.